Save each individual sheet in a google spreadsheet as its own PDF on Google Drive with Apps Scripts
I have a spreadsheet with 46 sheets in it. I would like to be able to hide 4 of them and then send the rest to google drive as PDFs. It should not require button clicks to send the files.
I found this out there and modified it to hide sheets prior to export, but it downloads to local drive and requires input, instead of sending to google drive automaticaly.
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  hideSheet("test2");
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(!sheet.isSheetHidden()){
      var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); 
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var str = '<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'" >';
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Click the button to download");
    }
  })
}

function hideSheet(sheetName) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).hideSheet();
}


To send the PDFs directly to Google Drive without requiring manual intervention you save the PDFs to Google Drive directly
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  hideSheet("test2");
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(!sheet.isSheetHidden()){
      var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); 
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      
      // Save PDF to Google Drive so you don't have to do it manually later
      var folderSave = DriveApp.getRootFolder(); // make this where you want to save it.
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");
      // this should make the file 
      folderSave.createFile(blob);
    }
  });
}

function hideSheet(sheetName) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).hideSheet();
}


Thank you this was very helpful. I was able to use this on my small test of 3 sheets but when I attempted to use it on 46 sheets I received this error
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

added an 8-second pause to the loop and now it works.
